# Get xml node value using it's attribute value

Tags: jquery, xml, jquery-selectors

Below is my xml

```
<wplc:field id="title">Alex Kane</wplc:field>
```

Here I need to get the value Alex Kane using it's id title like

```
$(this).find("[id='title']").text();
```

But above is not working, how can I do that?

Comment: what is `this` referring to?

Comment: Did you try to print 'this'? Are u sure its your xml

Comment: It works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/7corcbwq/2/

Comment: You can also do.. .("#title").text();

Answer (score 0):

you can access directly:

```
<wplc:field id="title">Alex Kane</wplc:field>
```

and from script side you access using

```
$("body").find("[id='title']").text();
```

Better you Check your`$(this)` value whether it will come correct or not.